# wcf return more than one instance of a class to client

Tags: wcf, class

The problem: I have a web service up and running ok, the problem I have is that i need to return more than one instance of a class and have no real idea how to do this.

I have a loop set up in the service:

```
If localtab.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Do While i <= localtab.Rows.Count
                Mbr.Urn = localtab.Rows(i).Item(0) & vbNullString
                Mbr.Title = localtab.Rows(i).Item(1) & vbNullString
                Mbr.Initials = localtab.Rows(i).Item(2) & vbNullString
                Mbr.Surname = localtab.Rows(i).Item(3) & vbNullString
                Mbr.Address1 = localtab.Rows(i).Item(4) & vbNullString
                Mbr.Address2 = localtab.Rows(i).Item(5) & vbNullString
                Mbr.Address3 = localtab.Rows(i).Item(6) & vbNullString
                Mbr.Town = localtab.Rows(i).Item(7) & vbNullString
                Mbr.County = localtab.Rows(i).Item(8) & vbNullString
                Mbr.Country = localtab.Rows(i).Item(9) & vbNullString
                Mbr.Postcode = localtab.Rows(i).Item(10) & vbNullString
                Mbr.msg = "Success"

                i = i + 1
            Loop
        Else
            Mbr.msg = "Fail - no record found"
        End If
```

And i know that this works fine as it returns the last member listed in the DB.  Doing something like `Mbr(i).urn` etc... won't work as when I loop through i, it is only ever going to return the first instance, and once the service has returned once it will stop.

Below is the code from the client end calling the service - simple enough, all I am looking for just now is for a message box with each surname to be displayed.

```
Dim abMem As New ArdbegMember
    Dim retMem As ArdbegMember

    abMem.Downloaded = "N"

    Try
        cc.Open()
        retMem = cc.MbrReq(abMem)
        MesgBox(retMem.Surname)
        cc.Close()
```

What I need to know is how to pass a full recordset back to the client

**EDIT**

So based on the suggestions below, my code now looks like this -

```
Dim results As List(Of ArdbegMember)
            Dim i As Integer = 0

            'assign values from the table to the ArdbegMember object
            If localtab.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Do While i <= localtab.Rows.Count
                    Mbr.Urn = localtab.Rows(i).Item(0) & vbNullString
                    Mbr.Title = localtab.Rows(i).Item(1) & vbNullString
                    Mbr.Initials = localtab.Rows(i).Item(2) & vbNullString
                    Mbr.Surname = localtab.Rows(i).Item(3) & vbNullString
                    Mbr.Address1 = localtab.Rows(i).Item(4) & vbNullString
                    Mbr.Address2 = localtab.Rows(i).Item(5) & vbNullString
                    Mbr.Address3 = localtab.Rows(i).Item(6) & vbNullString
                    Mbr.Town = localtab.Rows(i).Item(7) & vbNullString
                    Mbr.County = localtab.Rows(i).Item(8) & vbNullString
                    Mbr.Country = localtab.Rows(i).Item(9) & vbNullString
                    Mbr.Postcode = localtab.Rows(i).Item(10) & vbNullString
                    Mbr.msg = "Success"

                    i = i + 1

                    results.Add(Mbr)
                Loop
            Else
                Mbr.msg = "Fail - no record found"
            End If

            'Tidy up
            dataAdapter.Dispose()
            Cmd.Dispose()
            oConn.Close()

            'Return the ArdbegMember object
            Return results
```

And the error being thrown is now -

```
Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of ArdbegWeb.ArdbegMember)' cannot be converted to 'ArdbegWeb.ArdbegMember'.
```

Comment: Intriguing: `ArdbegMember` - as in Ardbeg on Islay? ;-) Love your stuff!

Comment: Sure is! Haha - this has caused me no end of problems tho!

Comment: Computer grief is always a good reason to pour another dram :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help marc, the solution was blindingly obvious and i shouldn't have missed it!

`Do While i <= localtab.Rows.Count` should have read `Do While i <= localtab.Rows.Count-1`.  The loop was repeating on itself one too many times causing issues when it was trying to return Mbr to the client side!

Answer (score 2):

You can always create a service that returns a `List<T>` given you define a concrete type for `<T>`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IYourService
{
   [OperationContract]
   public List<ArdbegMember> GetMembers();  
}
```

Assuming you have a data contract class:

```
[DataContract]
public class ArdbegMember
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    .... (and so forth - define all the properties you need on your `ArdbegMember`)
}
```

In your service implementation, you could then write:

```
public class YourService : IYourService
{
   public List<ArdbegMember> GetMembers()
   {
       List<ArdbegMember> results = new List<ArdbegMember>();

       // load your `localtab` somehow
       foreach(DataRow row in localtab.Rows)
       {
           ArdbegMember member = new ArdbegMember();
           // set the properties, based on the "row"

           results.Add(member);
       }

       return results;
   }  
}
```

So now you have a WCF service with a single method called `GetMembers()` (you probably want to pass in some search criteria, etc. - in your real service) and returns back a list of `ArdbegMember` objects.

Some good WCF resources:

- The [WCF Developer Center](https://web.archive.org/web/20090107214706/http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF)
- [Beginner's Guide to Windows Communication Foundation](https://web.archive.org/web/20120804143818/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf.aspx)
- [Resources and Community](https://web.archive.org/web/20120426162742/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/netframework/dd939788.aspx)

Interested in a book? I would recommend [Learning WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627) by Michele Leroux Bustamante. She covers all the necessary topics, and in a very understandable and approachable way. This will teach you everything - basics, intermediate topics, security, transaction control and so forth - that you need to know to write high quality, useful WCF services.

[image: Learning WCF]

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - i am pretty new to all things web service and inherited this half finished project from my predecessor so struggling to get to grips completely.  Could you explain this a bit more or provide some links if possible?

Comment: I've had a read through what you've posted, thanks very much - it definately makes sense what you are doing...I will try and work this into VB and see if I can get up and running.  I may be back with more questions! Cheers

Comment: Think I must be almost there - the error i am getting is as follows `Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of ArdbegWeb.ArdbegMember)' cannot be converted to 'ArdbegWeb.ArdbegMember'.` so it doesnt seem to want to return the list of ArdbegMember?

Comment: @allanmayberry88: it seems that you are assigning a **list** of members to a single member somewhere - that won't work.

Comment: @allanmayberry88: btw: if you changed your service to return a `List(Of ArdbegWeb.ArdbegMember)` - did you also update your client side proxy to be aware of this change?? Otherwise your client will still expect to get back a single `ArdbegWeb.ArdbegMember`, but your service now returns a list thereof

Comment: Thanks again for your help up till now - I am fairly sure that I now have the actual web service set up to return a list, but on the client side I am getting the following CommunicationException - `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` This happens as soon as I try to call the function in the webservice.

Comment: So the problem seems to be here - 
`Public Function MbrReq(ByVal ArdbegMember1 As ArdbegWeb.ArdbegMember) As List(Of ArdbegWeb.ArdbegMember) Implements IArdbegWeb.MbrReq
Return MyBase.Channel.MbrReq(ArdbegMember1)
End Function`
I think I understand that the client side isn't expecting the list to come through if I understand this error properly - in which case, what have I not changed?